# Loop doesn't stop + doesn't update random string

Tags: javascript, while-loop, deployd

There are two issues with my script: It doesn't update random every new round and keeps running forever. But in my opinion it should do both .. How can I make the loop recognize that this.short has changed?

```
while ( ! this.short) {
    random = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,7).toUpperCase();

    dpd.links.get({short: random}, function(res, err) {
        if (err)
            cancel('Error', 500);

        if ( ! res.length)
            this.short = random;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Math.random() actually returns a [pseudo-random number seeded from the current time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random). So it's not surprising that it doesn't update for every loop.

As for `this.short`: `this` always refers to the “owner” of the current function. So the `this` in `this.short = random` is probably different from the `this` in your while loop. What you need to do is assign `this` to a variable first. For example:

```
var current = this;
while (!current.short) {
    ...
    current.short = random;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use something different there. But the script still doesn't stop the loop

Comment: where/when would you expect the loop to stop? if !this.short and res.length are true, the loop will run forever.

Comment: Line 9 should do it. I'm waiting for a random which gives me a result.length of 0 and right then it should stop

Comment: Well, if random is not updated (cf. my answer) then why should result.length change?

Comment: I've updated the random function and it still keeps running. As the db is empty at the moment any first result should have the result.length of 0. If I change this.short outside my closure the loop seems to get the difference, interestingly.